# For a holomorphic function, does Newton's difference quotient converge uniformly on compact sets?

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

Let $K\subset A\subset C$, where $K$ is compact, $A$ is open, and $C$ is the complex numbers.
Let $f:C\rightarrow C$ be holomorphic on $A$ (holomorphic = complex derivative exists for all points in $A$).
Is it true that on $K$, $[f(z+\Delta z) - f(z)]/\Delta z$ converges uniformly as $\Delta z\rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the generalized Cauchy integral formula, integrating around a suitable contour.